# How create internal ActiveMQ on port 61616 with Fuse Karaf 7?

Tags: java, jms, osgi, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

i'm desperated.

i must be very stupid by the documentation i find out on this url:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.0/html/deploying_into_apache_karaf/deployjmsbroker

Fuse 7.0 does not ship with a default internal broker, but it is designed to interface with your external JMS brokers.

After all the tutorial i get this error:

```java
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[file-to-jms-route ] [file-to-jms-route ] [file://work/jms/input                                                         ] [         9]
[file-to-jms-route ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[file-to-jms-route ] [to1               ] [jms:queue:incomingOrders?transacted=true                                      ] [         7]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316) ~[231:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.20.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169) ~[231:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.20.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487) ~[231:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:4.3.20.RELEASE_1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:526) ~[229:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:440) ~[229:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:394) ~[229:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:157) ~[229:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148) ~[60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:452) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:219) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:183) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101) [60:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.21.0.fuse-731003-redhat-00003]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:846) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:282) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:277) ~[?:?]
        at Proxy3be079fd_3adf_4977_94f5_116eed5821f8.createConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474) ~[?:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:844) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:282) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:277) ~[?:?]
        at Proxy3be079fd_3adf_4977_94f5_116eed5821f8.createConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474) ~[?:?]
        ... 22 more
```

Because there is no service listen on port 61616:

```
 netstat -lutanp | grep 61616
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong anyone have a more specific documentation on the passage to do for install a internal ActiveMQ Borker on Fuse Karaf 7.X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i just installed a external activemq server, i haven't find a way to resolve this issue on the embedded activemq of Karaf in RedHat Fuse

Comment: Did you do any modification in configurations in GitHub project when accessing the external ActiveMQ server ?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify standalone-full.xml config file in jboss server

```
<interface name = "public">
    <inet-address value = "$ {jboss.bind.address: 0.0.0.0}" />
</interface>
```

If you are not explicitly setting the "jboss.bind.address" when the server boots (either via -Djboss.bind.address or -b) then it will bind to 0.0.0.0.

However, if you have to bind to 0.0.0.0 then you see this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/266416) for more details on how to configure your connector(s) properly in that situation.

I have consulted this information [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/267476).

I hope it helps you

regards

Comment: From what I can tell Karaf is being used here as the container rather than JBoss so I don't think your answer here is relevant.